# How can I return an object from a recursive function upon completion only?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am calling a recursive function that is returning an object, the object is being returned on each iteration.

I wish to only return an object once the recursive operation has completed. rather than on each iteration.

```
  async fetchRecipe(recipe: any) {
    console.log("fetchRecipe");
    // Start with a root recipe
    let rootRecipe: Recipe = {
      id: recipe.id,
      name: recipe.name,
      ingredients: [],
      childRecipes: []
    }
    // Kick off recursive function
    let result = await this.recursivelyBuildRecipe(rootRecipe);
    console.log("Fetch Recipe returned");
    return result
  }

  async recursivelyBuildRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
    // fetches using the API
    console.log("recursivelyBuildRecipe");
    this.fetchChildren('http:///recipes/get_children', 'id=' + recipe.id)
      .then(async x => {
        await x.data.children.forEach((async(child: { type: any; ItemId: string; name: string; }) => {
          switch (child.type) {
            case 'ingredient':
              // if ingredient
              let ingredient: Ingredient = {
                id: child.ItemId,
                name: child.name,
                unit: 1
              }
              this.allIngredients.push(ingredient);
              recipe.ingredients.push(ingredient);
              break
            case 'recipe':
              let subRecipe: Recipe = {
                id: child.ItemId,
                name: child.name,
                ingredients: [],
                childRecipes: []
              }
              await this.recursivelyBuildRecipe(subRecipe)
              recipe.childRecipes.push(subRecipe)
              break
          }
        }))
      })
    // This is returning the same amount of times the recursive function is called, I want it to only return once complete.
    var obj = { "recipes": recipe, "ingredients": this.allIngredients }
    return await obj;
```

Comment: You're `await`-ing an object. That's the same as `return Promise.resolve({"recipes": ...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async recursivelyBuildRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {

  const fetch = await this.fetchChildren('http:///recipes/get_children', 'id=' + recipe.id);
  const asyncRecipe = await fetch.data.children.reduce(async (accPromise,child) => {
    const recipe = await accPromise;
    switch(child.type) {
      case 'ingredient':
        let ingredient: Ingredient = {
          id: child.ItemId,
          name: child.name,
          unit: 1
        }
        this.allIngredients.push(ingredient);
        recipe.ingredients.push(ingredient);
        break;
      case 'recipe':
        let subRecipe: Recipe = {
          id: child.ItemId,
          name: child.name,
          ingredients: [],
          childRecipes: []
        }
        await this.recursivelyBuildRecipe(subRecipe)
        recipe.childRecipes.push(subRecipe)
        break;    
    }

    return recipe;
  },Promise.resolve(recipe));

  return { "recipes": asyncRecipe, "ingredients": this.allIngredients }
}
```

1. Don't mix Promises and async/await syntax. There's nothing technically incorrect about it, but it's terribly confusing.
2. You need to iterate over each of the children retrieved and await them. The easiest way to do this, in my opinion, is in a reduce. Although this results in serial retrieval of children - it returns a single object at the end and is easier to reason about. If it's not fast enough, you could do it better with a Promise.all and merge the results yourself.
3. I'm not sure that the above syntax is 100% correct, but you should be able to get the idea:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand specifics here, but it seems what you can do in general is:

1. Add `await` for the `this.fetchChildren` (otherwise it seems like you're getting results because of mutation, not on time).
2. Add a second boolean parameter to the recursive function (i.e `isMainCall`), pass it only for the first time (when you start recursion) and add the return in the end into `if (isMainCall) return obj`